# Transpose of Julia DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, julia

Let's create Julia DataFrame

```
df=convert(DataFrame, rand(10, 4))
```

It would look like this. I am trying to take the transpose of this dataFrame. "transpose" function appears to be not working for Julia Data Frame as shown below.

[image]

I have used Python Pandas dataframe package extensively in the past.  In Python, it would be as easy as "df.T"  Please let me know a way to Tranpose this dataframe.

Comment: Usually you would like to transpose a matrix. Which is as easy as `M'` in Julia. If the matrix is embedded in a DataFrame, convert it to a matrix, transpose and then (if you must) back to a DataFrame. In the OP this would be `DataFrame(Matrix(df)')`

Comment: A great suggestion, But, that would mean the row names and column names in the original dataframe "df" are no longer respected.

Comment: Not sure there are any rownames in DataFrame. Have a look at NamedArrays. They support transpose and have row,column,dimension naming.

Comment: Careful that `'` is conjugate transpose, whereas regular transpose is `.'`. In practice, conjugate transpose is more common, which is why the syntax was chosen this way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same question and tried the strategy suggested in the comments to your question.  The problem I encountered, however, is that converting to a `Matrix` won't work if your DataFrame has `NA` values.  You have to change them to something else, then convert to a `Matrix`.  I had a lot of problems converting back to `NA` when I wanted to get from a `Matrix` back to a `DataFrame` type.

Here's a way to do it using `DataFrame`'s `stack` and `unstack` functions.

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = 5:8)
4×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 5     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 6     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 7     │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 8     │

julia> colnames = names(df)
2-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :A
 :B

julia> df[!, :id] = 1:size(df, 1)
1:4

julia> df
4×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B     │ id    │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 5     │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 6     │ 2     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 7     │ 3     │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 8     │ 4     │
```

Adding the `:id` column is suggested by the `DataFrame` documentation as a way to help with unstacking.

Now stack the columns you want to transpose:

```
julia> dfl = stack(df, colnames)
8×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ variable │ value │ id    │
│     │ Symbol   │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼──────────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ A        │ 1     │ 1     │
│ 2   │ A        │ 2     │ 2     │
│ 3   │ A        │ 3     │ 3     │
│ 4   │ A        │ 4     │ 4     │
│ 5   │ B        │ 5     │ 1     │
│ 6   │ B        │ 6     │ 2     │
│ 7   │ B        │ 7     │ 3     │
│ 8   │ B        │ 8     │ 4     │
```

Then unstack, switching the id and variable names (this is why adding the `:id` column is necessary).

```
julia> dfnew = unstack(dfl, :variable, :id, :value)
2×5 DataFrame
│ Row │ variable │ 1      │ 2      │ 3      │ 4      │
│     │ Symbol   │ Int64⍰ │ Int64⍰ │ Int64⍰ │ Int64⍰ │
├─────┼──────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ A        │ 1      │ 2      │ 3      │ 4      │
│ 2   │ B        │ 5      │ 6      │ 7      │ 8      │
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem with Stephen answer, is that order of columns is not preserved (try if you are not convinced with the following `DataFrame`

```
julia> df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = 5:8, AA = 15:18)
4×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B     │ AA    │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 5     │ 15    │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 6     │ 16    │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 7     │ 17    │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 8     │ 18    │
```

but this `DataFrame` can be transposed (keeping order of columns/rows) using:

```
julia> DataFrame([[names(df)]; collect.(eachrow(df))], [:column; Symbol.(axes(df, 1))])
3×5 DataFrame
│ Row │ column │ 1     │ 2     │ 3     │ 4     │
│     │ Symbol │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼────────┼───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ A      │ 1     │ 2     │ 3     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ B      │ 5     │ 6     │ 7     │ 8     │
│ 3   │ AA     │ 15    │ 16    │ 17    │ 18    │
```

Reference: https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/2065#issuecomment-568937464

Answer (score 0):

This works with dataframes that are not too complicated. One of the dataframe's columns is used to generate column names. The names of the other columns become row names.

```
function all_unique(v::Vector)::Bool
    return length(unique(v)) == length(v)
end

function df_add_first_column(
    df::DataFrame,
    colname::Union{Symbol,String},
    col_data
)
    df1 = DataFrame([colname => col_data])
    hcat(df1, df)
end

function df_transpose(df::DataFrame, col::Union{Symbol, String})::DataFrame
    @assert all_unique(df[!, col]) "Column `col` contains non-unique elements"

    function foo(i)
        string(df[i, col]) => collect(df[i, Not(col)])
    end

    dft = DataFrame(map(foo, 1:nrow(df)))

    return df_add_first_column(dft, "Row", filter(x -> x != string(col), names(df)))
end
```

Example:

```
df0 = DataFrame(A = [1, 2, 3], B = rand(3), C = rand(3))

    3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ A      B         C        
     │ Int64  Float64   Float64
─────┼───────────────────────────
   1 │     1  0.578605  0.590092
   2 │     2  0.350394  0.399114
   3 │     3  0.90852   0.710629

2×4 DataFrame
 Row │ Row     1         2         3        
     │ String  Float64   Float64   Float64
─────┼──────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ B       0.578605  0.350394  0.90852
   2 │ C       0.590092  0.399114  0.710629
```

Answer (score 0):

[`permutedims`](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#Base.permutedims) does this.

Often when you want to transpose a dataframe, you already have a column with names (Strings or Symbols):

[image]

[image]

---

In the asker's random matrix example..

```
df = DataFrame(rand(10, 4), :auto)
```

[image]

..there aren't any names for the new columns. So we'll use the row numbers:

```
df.id = string.(1:nrow(df))  # Add column with names
permutedims(df, "id", "")
```

[image]

We used the optional third argument of `permutedims` to rename the new `id` column to the empty string, which is not necessary but can be nice.